# Elastic Search - Refresh Vs Transaction Log

Tags: elasticsearch

I come across this statement from the linkhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/translog.html

> The translog is also used to provide real-time CRUD. When you try to retrieve, update, or delete a document by ID, it first checks the translog for any recent changes before trying to retrieve the document from the relevant segment. This means that it always has access to the latest known version of the document, in real-time.

However, Elastic search claims that near real timesearch, documents will be searchable once refresh is finished.  Is it that search query will look at transaction log first ?

Little confused, please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRUD is only when you try to...

> retrieve, update, or delete a document by ID

So when you CRUD a document (implied by ID), then Elastic looks up the translog first before fetching the document from the low-level segment file.

Search is a different thing and documents will only be searchable once the refresh phase is finished.

So, that's why CRUD is real-time but search is near real-time.

Comment: Is still CRUD realtime even in the cases if the document doesnt exist in transactionlog( perhaps after flush happened)

Comment: Does this still apply? The get API for version 6.x (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-get.html) states that the GET will refresh the index to "make the doc visible". But it doesn't seem like the GET triggers a refresh when I tested it locally. I'm a bit confused about the documentation too.